# How to convert magento1 extensions to magento2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

Is it possible to convert magento1 extensions to magento2?.I am searching but no perfect solution.Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I did't tried , but You can check below links :

https://github.com/magento/code-migration

https://github.com/unirgy/convertm1m2

https://www.slideshare.net/VladimirKerkhoff/convert-magento-1-extensions-to-magento-2